# How to draw(click/drag) an arbitrary area in the Yandex Map Api?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps, yandex-api

I need to make that functional: [Selected Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyU2t.png), but
I've never worked with yandex map api, so don't know how to do that. Help me please to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an area with Polygon object. Like this:

```
var myPolygon = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
            [[/*...*/]],
            [[/*...*/]]
        ]
    }
});
```

Look at [this example](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example exactly of what I wanted —https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_custom